# How to get meaningful revision graph with `git log`

Tags: git, git-log

I've quite a big repository with lots of branches and tags. In order to get a quick overview over the branches and tags I often use

```
git log --all --graph --simplify-by-decoration
```

However, this command oversimplifies the revision graph (which basically looks like this; `tag B`, `branch C`, and `branch D` all come after `tag A`, but are not direct children of `tag A`):

```
  tag B   branch C   branch D
       \     |     / 
           tag A
```

instead of

```
                  branch C   branch D
                    \        /
  tag B            last common ancestor Y
     \              /
     last common ancestor X
              |
             tag A
```

Hence, it is hard to see where the branches branched off.

Is there a way to get the desired output (i.e., includes the common ancestors)? - Using `sparse` adds all commits and, thus, is too noisy.

Comment: Do you need a console tool or can you use `gitk`?

Comment: I'd prefer console, but a solution for gitk would also be nice (I suppose here just some git log parameters needs to be configured, right? These could then also be used on the CLI).

Comment: Or some other GUI?

Comment: @matt No, no other GUI.

Comment: Did you try `--dense`?

Comment: There is no difference with `--dense`.

Comment: I'm guessing what's needed here is a flag you could pass to to `git log` that allowed you to specify how many "context commits" you'd like to see in between branches and tags.

Comment: Am I correct, MrTux?

Comment: @NeiNeto probably